# On finding an expression of this matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $M_n$ be a  $n × n$ matrix with real coefficients of which the entry in the $i$-th row and the $j$-th column equals 1 whenever $|i − j| ≤ 1$ and 0 otherwise.
Is it possible to find a general formula in terms of $n$ for the determinant of
$M_n$?

Comment: Well, do you know what a determinant is? Have you written out examples for some small $n$?

Answer (score 2):

$D_n=\det M_n$

By developing by the first column (and then by the first line for one of the two cofactors), you get $D_{n+2}=D_{n+1}-D_n$.

You can easily compute $D_1 = 1$ and $D_2 = 0$.

You can then notice that $D_{n+3}=D_{n+2}-D_{n+1}=\left(D_{n+1}-D_{n}\right)-D_{n+1}=-D_n$. So $D_{n+6}=D_n$.

Now, if you want a complicated expression, you can just chose your favorite $6$-periodic function $f$ so that $f(k)=D_k$ for $k\in\{1,\dots,6\}$. That is $f(1)=1,f(2)=0,f(3)=-1,f(4)=-1,f(5)=0,f(6)=1$.

For example, you could take $x\mapsto \cfrac{1}{\cos \left(k\right)}(\cos(c+kx))$ where $k=\cfrac{2\pi}{6}$ and $c=2$. The idea is simple : You use $k$ to make it $6$-periodic, then you make sure the zeroes are where they should be with $c$ and since you want $1$ or $-1$ when you don't get $0$, you scale it.